# Pusher notifications client not acknowledging userId token

Tags: pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to setup Pusher to receive push notifications from my server. I've gone through the docs and followed the instructions but I'm getting this error which I have no clue how to get past. If you help me sort it out it'll be like an early Christmas gift.

This is my client code:

```
        const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client({
            instanceId: 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX',
        });

        const beamsTokenProvider = new PusherPushNotifications.TokenProvider({
            url: "/Account/BeamsAuth/",
        });

        var currentUserId = `@User.Identity.GetUserId()`;

        beamsClient.start()
            .then(() => beamsClient.setUserId(currentUserId, beamsTokenProvider))
            .then(() => beamsClient.addDeviceInterest('WaitingForRide'))
            .then(() => beamsClient.getDeviceInterests())
            .then((interests) => console.log("Current interests: ", interests))
            .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered and subscribed!'))
            .catch(console.error);
```

This is my server code:

[image]

This is the error I'm seeing on my browser's console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token')
    at Client._callee14$ (push-notifications-cdn.js:2102)
    at tryCatch (push-notifications-cdn.js:82)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (push-notifications-cdn.js:308)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (push-notifications-cdn.js:134)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (push-notifications-cdn.js:770)
    at _next (push-notifications-cdn.js:792)
```

[image]

The token acquisition process to create an Authenticated User is described here: [image]

I'm positive that I've implemented the token acquisition process correctly but I can't seem to get past this error. It's a total curveball.

I'm really at a loss of what to do here. I tried researching this particular error but didn't get anything back on it. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @KenLee Thanks for your response. That part works. I've inspected the user id on the API side and it does in fact post the User's ID from the client to the server successfully. I'm going to post a picture demonstrating this. Just a sec!

Comment: @KenLee Yes that's the one. The docs here: https://pusher.com/docs/beams/concepts/authenticated-users/#authentication-process say that you are supposed to implement the token retrieval process yourself. I've added some more detail above.

Comment: @KenLee what I'm not sure about is why the javascript code on the client-side is saying it can't read the token. From the picture I pasted above, the server-side code is clearly returning a token string. The console doesn't provide anything more than the error I've pasted above. So I'm left scratching my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure the token is in JSON format, such as:

```
{"token":"XXXXXXXXX"}
```